# Como fazer upload de arquivos, enviando o anexo como email no laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, envio-de-email, file-upload

Estou fazendo uma página de trabalhe conosco com upload de arquivos(currículos), gostaria de enviar esse arquivo por anexo de email, mas estou meio sem rumo. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Controller

```
    public function trabalheConosco(RequestNewsletter $request)
{

    $data['nomeDaEmpresa'] = "Arantes Nutrição Animal";
    $data['nomeTrabalhe'] = $request->input("nomeTrabalhe");
    $data['sobrenome'] = $request->input("sobrenome");
    // $data['anexo'] = $request->input("anexo");
    $data['emailTrabalhe'] = $request->input("emailTrabalhe");
    $data['dataDeNascimento'] = $request->input("dataDeNascimento");
    $data['area'] = $request->input("area");
    $data['mensagemTrabalhe'] = $request->input("mensagemTrabalhe");
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i');

    $data['dataDeEnvio'] = $date;
    Mail::send('emails.trabalhe', $data, function($message){
        $message->to('evandroi10as@gmail.com', 'Teste')
        ->subject('Currículo');
        $message->attach($anexo);
    });
    $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Currículo cadastrado com sucesso.');
    return redirect('trabalhe-conosco');
}
```

View

```
            <form action="{{ url('trabalhe-conosco') }}" method="POST" class="row">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                    <p><strong>Dados Pessoais</strong></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-4" {{ $errors->has('nomeTrabalhe') ? ' has-error' : '' }}>
                    <input type="text" name="nomeTrabalhe" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome: ">
                    @if ($errors->has('nomeTrabalhe'))
                        <span class="help-block">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('nomeTrabalhe') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" name="sobrenome" class="form-control" placeholder="Sobrenome: ">
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                    <input id="anexo" type="file" name="anexo" style="display: none"><label for='anexo' class="form-control" style="height: 48px;line-height: 35px;background-color: #a8cf45;">Anexar Currículo<i class="fa fa-paperclip" aria-hidden="true"></i></label></input>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail: ">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" name="data_de_nascimento" class="form-control" placeholder="Data de Nascimento: ">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" name="area_de_interesse" class="form-control" placeholder="Área de Interesse: ">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                    <textarea name="mensagem" class="animated form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Mensagem: "></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                    <button class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
```

RequestNewsletter

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'emailnewsletter.required' => 'O campo Email é obrigatório.',
        'emailnewsletter.email' => 'O campo Email deve ser um email válido',
        'emailnewsletter.min' => 'O campo Email deve ter pelo menos :min caracteres.',
    ];
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'emailnewsletter' =>  'required|email|min:7',
    ];
}
```

Route

```
Route::post('trabalhe-conosco', 'Front\MailController@trabalheConosco');
```

Comment: Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pelo stackoverflow, conheça um pouco das regras e boas práticas. Depois, edite sua pergunta e insira o código do que você já tentou...

Comment: Como você está fazendo ? Tem algum código ?
Para isso usará a classe `Mail` do Laravel.

Comment: Estou tentando assim @Gumball

Comment: Seu formulário está sem o atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"` para envio de arquivos.

Comment: Obrigado @Gumball vou tentar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, terá que colocar o atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"` em seu `<form>`. Ficando assim:

```
<form action="{{ url('trabalhe-conosco') }}" method="POST" class="row" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Depois na função **Mail**:

Acrescente isso:

```
Mail::send('emails.trabalhe', $data, function($message) use ($data){
    $message->to('evandroi10as@gmail.com', 'Teste')
    ->subject('Currículo')
    ->attach($data['anexo']->getRealPath(), array(
        'as'   => 'file-.' . $data['anexo']->getClientOriginalExtension(), 
        'mime' => $data['anexo']->getMimeType());
    );
});
```

Request do arquivo. Descomente e troque `input` por `file`.

```
$data['anexo'] = $request->file("anexo");
```

Comment: Tentei desse jeito mas, aparece esse erro:  FatalThrowableError in MailController.php line 74:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Comment: Código corrigido.

Comment: agora dá esse FatalThrowableError in MailController.php line 74:
Call to a member function getRealPath() on null

Comment: Você descomentou o `$data['anexo']` ?

Comment: Editei meu post, veja a última atualização.

Comment: Sim @Gumball valeu, me ajudou muito!